# View Container vs Multiple ViewControllers vs Hidden Views Single ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a View Controller and need to segue into another View Controller (which is customized based on what scenario I want to show). Trying to decide what is the best approach here in regards to simplicity vs efficiency

Three options I can think of:

(a) Have my View Controller segue into a View Controller that holds a View Container linked to multiple View Controllers

(b) Have my View Controller segue into a View Controller with multiple views that can be hidden and rearranged

(c) Have my View Controller segue into different View Controllers depending upon the criteria

I'm still uncertain how much each View Controller should differ from each other, but given that one View Controller might segue into another View Controller that's irrelevant for the other two scenarios, what are your guys' thoughts on the three approaches in terms of code complexity, ease of use, general efficiency in terms of speed/memory management. It's possible that the View Controllers that are being segued into might differ by just a little, but also by a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all depends on difference between viewControllers for each scenario. BUT what I can certainly say is do not use varriant (B), because even if difference seems tiny now, as only it begins growing, your code that compose views will becomes more complicated and unreadable, at least in my case it usually happens. So, if you must show different viewControllers with same or pretty similar use (e.g. save for, show list, select item from list. go next, go previouse), try to use one viewController and load different views that are already composed. And if usage of those controllers different - use multiple controllers.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "use one viewController and load different views that are already composed" - are you referring to method (A)? Because you said load different "VIEWS that are already composed" so I'm a bit confused as how you will load different views, unless you mean view CONTROLLERS

Comment: @SimplyLearning, nope, I meant that you could load different views for your viewController through - (void)loadView methods of UIViewController, or add suitable contentView to your controller's view.

Comment: I'm a little confused, how is what you're suggesting here different from my Method (B)? To clarify, my Method (B) was referring to designing views in StoryBoard, then hiding/showing them programatically. That seems to be almost the same approach you are suggesting no?

Comment: @SimplyLearning, hm, First I was thinking that in method (B) you meant to make one view with number of subviews (buttons, textfield and other controls) and show/hide them, appropriate to scenario, and looks I misunderstood you. So, If under variant B you meant to create multiple completed views (that are conforms to same protocol or even inherited from same base view to let controller know determined way how to deal with them) than yes, my answer and your variant B is quite similar!